# Is there any alternative approach to implement WebRTC SFU, to have only 1 upload stream?

Tags: c++, webrtc, p2p, video-conferencing, mesh-network

I have a server which is able to relay the WebRTC media data from A to B. For the video conferencing, if we go with P2P approach then a mesh network is created. Whenever P2P doesn't work, we can have this relay server.

The main problem is that in the mesh network, the number of upload link is "N - 1" for N participants. Hence the number of connection goes upto N * (N-1). Usually mesh network allows 5-6 stable connections.

Many online sources suggest to implement SFU. If SFU decrypts the media data and then re-encrypts for every peer then that virtually requires a WebRTC component on the server side.
Are there any lightweight C/C++ based library which helps in this regard?

Any better alternative strategy for the same?

BTW, I tried to share the same offer to all the peers with their own answer, but as expected it didn't work. The peer gets disconnected after receiving few chunks.

---

I have referred below related posts:

- [WebRTC - scalable live stream broadcasting / multicasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318983/webrtc-scalable-live-stream-broadcasting-multicasting)
- [Multi-party WebRTC without SFU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054484/multi-party-webrtc-without-sfu)
- [Can I re-use an "offer" in WebRTC for mulitple connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190152/can-i-re-use-an-offer-in-webrtc-for-mulitple-connections)

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few free and open source projects that implement an SFU:

- [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/jitsi-videobridge/) is probably the best known, but it is written in Java, and might therefore be unsuitable in some deployments;
- [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) is written in C; it is small, efficient, and well supported, but might not be the easiest to understand;
- [Ion-SFU](https://github.com/pion/ion-sfu) and [Galène](https://galene.org) are written in Go, and might be easier to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Janus is officially supported for Linux. Are you aware of any C++ based cross platform library or a subset, which can generate offer/answer SDPs and then encode/decode the stream. Quite equivalent to what Chrome browser does. Even a minimal WebRTC subset of Chrome is also fine. But not sure, how to set it up.

Comment: @jch what do you think of mediasoup?

Comment: I'm not good at reading node.js code, so I haven't looked at it much.  Sorry.