# Can we send un-encrypted media RTP by disabling fingerprint in the WebRTC offer / answer?

Tags: javascript, encryption, webrtc, dtls, sfu

Attempting to implement an [SFU](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/), where all the WebRTC peers upload their unencrypted media streams to our customized server; so that they can be distributed to other peers in a loop without any decryption / re-encryption worries.
This is because, [Haven't found any source code to decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71028698).

For that, I tried to generate an offer at JS side using `createOffer()` and before feeding it to `setLocalDescription()`, I removed the `"a=fingerprint:sha-256 xx:YY..."` from it. However, it gives an error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute `'setLocalDescription'` on `'RTCPeerConnection'`: Failed to set local offer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint.

There is an interface available called `RTCDtlsFingerprint` which *might* help in disabling fingerprint, but not sure how to use it.

Is there a way to disable fingerprint or DTLS-SRTP and hack it to send an unencrypted data?

Answer (score 2):

You can not disable encryption (with the exception of [the disable-webrtc-encryption](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-webrtc-encryption) which is *not* available in the stable version of Chrome).

This is a MUST level requirement in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8827#section-6.5

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How the traditional SFU-s work? Do they decrypt and re-encrypt the streams for each peer individually? What is the best approach to implement a SFU in your opinion?

Comment: the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65447423/4352772 still applies